# why option selected doesn't comes first

Tags: php, html

I have created a PHP code to echo the following div

```
<div id="main_catsel">
<select id="maincat" >

    <option value="1">none</option>
    <option value="2">Computer</option>
    <option value="4">Refrigerator</option>
    <option value="13" selected="selected" >Grinder</option>
    <option value="21">Bed</option>

</select>
</div>
```

I am using the option values and name as result from query . But now the default result still shown first is according to the id not according to selected="selected". Can any one sugsest a solution for this. Cant remove the id ,because its needed for insertion.

```
  $maincat .='<div class="main_catsel">';
     $sqlmaincat = $ilance->db->query("SELECT
            cid FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "seller_profile 
            WHERE userid = '" . $uid . "'");
    $row = $ilance->db->fetch_array($sqlmaincat);
    $sqlcat = $ilance->db->query("SELECT
            cid,title_spa 
            FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "categories 
            WHERE parentid = '0'
            ");
         if ($ilance->db->num_rows($sqlcat) > 0)
         {
          $maincat .='<h2><select id="maincat">';
           while ($rows = $ilance->db->fetch_array($sqlcat))
            {  
             if($rows['cid']==$row['cid'])
             {
              $maincat .='<option selected="selected" value="'.$rows['cid'].'">'.$rows['title_spa'].'</option>';
              }
              else
              {
                $maincat .='<option value="'.$rows['cid'].'">'.$rows['title_spa'].'</option>';
                }
             }  
                $maincat .='</select></h2>';
       }
        $maincat .='</div>';
```

Comment: Could you give as any live example? I pasted your html code result and it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/GLDFR/

Comment: it even works fine in IE, are you sure your php scripts outputs html exactly like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What browser are you using?

["On SGML and HTML"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3.4.2) points out that some browsers only support the minimized form, i.e. `selected` rather than `selected="selected"`.

Or maybe you previously selected something, and your browser is remembering your choice.  Try holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> and clicking the Reload button, or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>.

Or maybe the your browser is caching an older version of the page.  Again Shift+Reload should help.  Browser-specific details at [Bypass your cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aBypass_your_cache).

Comment: Suspect it's that the browser is remembering previous input - yes to Shift-Refresh.

Comment: Yes, Firefox remembers whatever was selected last when you refresh, not what is set as "selected".

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you just do like this 
 $("select#maincat").val("13");

Thats it. just try this and Let me know further.